# p:dialog not showing on click

Tags: primefaces

I am using PrimeFaces 3 and my xhtml page is given below.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<f:view xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">
    <h:head>
        <h:outputScript name="jquery.js" library="css"></h:outputScript>
    </h:head>


    <h:body>
        <p:panel id="allPaymentMethods" header="Payment Method"
            style="font-weight: bold;font-size:14px"
            rendered="#{userRegistrationVo.paymentmethod}">
            <table width="100%">
                <tr>
                    <td>You can pay<br></br> <p:graphicImage
                            value="/images/dd.jpg" height="80" width="120" /><br></br> 
                            <p:commandButton id="showEbpDialog" type="button"
                                value="Via Bank" onclick="ebpDlg.show()" >
                            </p:commandButton>
                    </td>

                </tr>
            </table>

            <!-- epayment dialog starts here -->
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />

            <!-- epayment dialog ends here -->

            <p:dialog widgetVar="ebpDlg" modal="true" width="700" height="500">
                <p:panel header="Generate EBP for Bank Payment">
                    <p:commandButton value="Print" type="button" icon="ui-icon-print">
                        <p:printer target="generateebp" />
                    </p:commandButton>


                    <p:panel id="generateebp">
                        <table width="100%">
                            <tr>
                                <td colspan="3">
                                    <table width="100%">
                                        <tr>
                                            <td></td>
                                            <td>
                                                <!-- <h:commandButton update="generateebp"
                                                    action="#{controller.payViaBank}" type="button"
                                                    value="Generate EBP No." oncomplete="hideGenerateButton()"
                                                    rendered="#{userRegistrationVo.hideButton}" id="ebpButton">
                                                    <f:ajax render="generateebp" execute="@this">
                                                    </f:ajax>

                                                </h:commandButton> -->
                                                 <p:commandButton 
                                                    value="E-payment" action="#{controller.payViaBank}"
                                                    process="@this" update="generateebp">
                                                </p:commandButton>
                                            </td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td></td>
                                            <td align="center" valign="top"><p:graphicImage
                                                    value="/images/nepal_logo.png" height="60" width="90" /> <br></br>
                                                <br></br></td>

                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td></td>
                                            <td align="center" valign="top"><h:outputLabel
                                                    value="लोक सेवा आयोग" style="font-size:14px;" /></td>
                                        </tr>
                                        <tr>
                                            <td></td>
                                            <td align="center"><h:outputLabel
                                                    value="परिक्षा शुल्क तिर्न EBP नम्बर लिनुहोस् ।    "
                                                    style="font-size:14px;" /></td>

                                        </tr>
                                    </table>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>

                        <!-- viewing table -->

                        <table style="text-align: center" class="ebpTable">

                            <tr>
                                <td><h:outputLabel value="Advertisement Code"
                                        style="background-color:#EAF0F8"></h:outputLabel></td>
                                <td><h:outputLabel value="Total Amount Due"
                                        style="background-color:#EAF0F8"></h:outputLabel></td>
                                <td><h:outputLabel value="EBP Code"
                                        style="background-color:#EAF0F8"></h:outputLabel></td>
                                <td><h:outputLabel value="Last Submission Date"
                                        style="background-color:#EAF0F8"></h:outputLabel></td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                                <td><h:outputText value="#{epaymentVo.advertisementcode}" />
                                </td>

                                <td><h:outputText value="#{epaymentVo.total}" /></td>
                                <td><h:outputText value="#{userRegistrationVo.ebpNumber}" />
                                </td>
                                <td><h:outputText
                                        value="#{userRegistrationVo.lastApplicationDateNp}" /></td>
                            </tr>
                        </table>

                        <br />
                        <br />
                        <p>
                            मिती
                            <h:outputLabel
                                value="#{userRegistrationVo.lastApplicationDateNp}"></h:outputLabel>
                            गते बैन्किङ समय भित्र भुक्तान गरी सक्नुपर्नेछ। अन्यथा स्वय
                            उम्मेद्वार जिम्मेवार हुनु पर्ने छ ।
                        </p>

                    </p:panel>


                </p:panel>
            </p:dialog>
            <br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <hr />
            <p:commandButton process="@this" update="@form" id="returnToAdvtBtn"
                value="Back To Advertisement" action="#{controller.returnToAdvt}">
            </p:commandButton>
        </p:panel>
    </h:body>
</f:view>
```

I am trying to open simple dialog box while I click the button. Now I am using PrimeFaces `p:commandButton` to achieve it. When I click the "Via Bank" button nothing happens (no dialog box opens). So when I go to the console of the browser, I see:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: ebpDlg is not defined

but I have clearly defined `ebpDlg` dialog box. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: 1: upgrade, 2:remove the superfluous jquery.js from your h:head

Comment: i removed everything from head tag. but it is still not working.

Comment: Don't think it's related to the dialog not being available, but I would advice to include your body content in a `h:form`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add id for your dialog box same as widgetVar.

```
 <p:dialog id="ebpDlg"  widgetVar="ebpDlg" modal="true" width="700" height="500">
```

If calling using widgetVar you need add PF function like  `PF('ebpDlg').show()`

but I think this will work for above version 4.0 .So kindly check your version also.

Comment: Adding an `id` attribute is not required. You indeed need something like `PF('yourWidgetVar')`, but I'm not sure about PrimeFaces 3. I think that function was renamed in PF 5.

Comment: See https://code.google.com/archive/p/primefaces/wikis/MigrationGuide.wiki, so it will probably also work on 3.

Comment: .. oh, and if you are not sure about an answer, it is better to just leave a comment. You can gain reputation to do so by improving questions for example.

Comment: Ok will do it sure from next time thanks for  your valuable suggestion